# Partition function inequality for Gibbs states associated with graphs

Tags: quantum-information, partition-function

Suppose I have two undirected graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with the same vertex set $V$ and let $A_1$ and $A_2$ denote their respective adjacency matrices. Define the intersection of the two graphs $G_\cap$ as the graph having adjacency matrix $A_\cap$ whose elements are

$A^{i,j}_{\cap} \equiv A^{i,j}_1 A^{i,j}_2$

Similarly, define the union of the two graphs $G_\cup$ as the graph having adjacency matrix $A_\cup$ with elements

$A^{i,j}_\cup \equiv A^{i,j}_1 + A^{i,j}_2 - A^{i,j}_1 A^{i,j}_2$

Let $L_1$, $L_2$, $L_{\hspace{0.025cm}\cap}$ and $L_{\hspace{0.025cm}\cup}$ be the **combinatorial laplacian matrices** associated with the graphs denoted by their subscripts. In particular, each laplacian $L$ is defined as $L \equiv  D - A$, where $D$ is the degree matrix of the graph associated with $L$.

It turns out that $L_\cup = L_1 + L_2 - L_\cap$.

Define the Gibbs state density matrix at inverse temperature $\beta \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ associated with a graph $G$ by

$\rho_G(\beta) \equiv \displaystyle\frac{\exp(-\beta L_G)}{Z_G}$

where the normalizing partition function is $Z_G \equiv \mathrm{Tr}[\exp(-\beta L_G)]$. One can easily show that, in the operator sense, $L_{\hspace{0.025cm}\cup} \geq L_1 \geq L_{\hspace{0.025cm}\cap}$ and $L_{\hspace{0.025cm}\cup} \geq L_2 \geq L_{\hspace{0.025cm}\cap}$ (see below for the proof of this statement). By using the dual Weyl inequalities, that this implies that the ordered eigenvalues of these laplacian matrices satisfy the following inequalities

$\lambda^{\hspace{0.025cm}\cup}_i \geq \lambda^{(1)}_i\hspace{-0.1cm},\lambda^{(2)}_i \geq \lambda^\cap_i, i \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\}$.

I am having trouble proving the following (numerically-observed) inequality regarding the partition functions

$Z_\cup \geq \displaystyle\frac{Z_1 Z_2}{Z_1 + Z_2}$

Any ideas?

Proof of partial ordering for laplacian matrices associated with subgraphs:

Consider a subgraph $H$ of a graph $G$, both graphs having the same vertex set, and denote by $L_H$ and $L_G$ their respective combinatorial laplacian matrices as defined above. Then, because $L \equiv L_G - L_H$ is a laplacian matrix, $L_G - L_H \geq 0$ in the operator sense. This relation can be applied to the situation in the question above because $G_\cap \subseteq G_1, G_2 \subseteq G_\cup$.

Comment: *"numerically observed"* -- On which cases/samples?

Comment: I randomly (uniformly) sampled hundreds of N by N laplacian matrices for N = 2,3,...,20 and the partition function inequality holds in all cases for all values of the inverse temperature.

Comment: How did you sample? Why no larger N? Which temperatures? How many samples?

Comment: I used Mathematica to generate random adjacency matrices by sampling from the set {0,1}, with probability 1/2 for 0 and for 1, for each matrix element. Then, I symmetrized these matrices. To get the laplacian matrices, I computed the row sums to get the degree matrices and subtracted the respective adjacency matrices. The reason I cannot get larger N is because Mathematica restarts its kernel every time I try to plot both sides of the partition function inequality for N > 20. My plots have $\beta \in (0,40)$. Like I said, I have generated hundreds of samples.

Comment: Could you maybe add the definition of your Laplacian? Wikipedia lists 3 different ones. It might also be neat to say how those inequalities on the L's can be proven (if it is short; maybe at the bottom of the question) - maybe it gives some insight?  ---  BTW, I'd rather try matlab or the like; and hundreds is not much, just assume the measure of the counterexamples is 1/1000.

Comment: Ok. I will add the definition. The inequalities on the L's can be proven in two lines so I will add it. And yes, I agree that MatLab/Python/C++ would be better tools. I was just prototyping in Mathematica to generate conjectures. If I can prove it without going to these tools, it would be great. However, it is proving hard to do so.

Comment: Matlab shouldn't really be harder than mathematica.  I guess you tried using Golden-Thompson and related inequalities?

Comment: Yea. It's an accident of my history that I have not used MatLab for scientific computing. And yes, Golden-Thompson gives you an inequality in the wrong direction. There is a paper by Hiai and Petz that gives the lower bound on $\mathrm{Tr}[\exp(A+B)]$ but I cannot compute the lower bound explicitly for Gibbs states (see my other post regarding the lower bound on the quantum relative entropy).

Comment: Ah, that was you with the other post.  (Username sounded familiar ... ;) )  Do you need it for this problem, and/or what is the relation?  If there is a relation, linking the questions to each other might help.  (And as I said in the other question, your conditions won't allow for a stregthening beyond the general case! - If you edit the conditions into the question, I'm happy to put this as an answer.)

Comment: I don't necessarily need it for this problem but it seems possibly relevant due to the fact that it gives the inequality in the correct direction for $\mathrm{Tr}[\exp(A+B)]$. Also, in the other question, I was not looking for a "strengthening", just a way to actually simplify the logarithm of a product of three Gibbs-type density matrices.

Comment: BTW, I did some numerics with N=50, seems to hold.